# Twilio Twimlet FindMe

Tags: twilio

I'm using C# to replace our existing IVR with Twilio Voice and believe I need to use the FindMe twimlet.  Our objective is to hunt" an agent down using round robin.  So, call one agent, if they don't pickup, call the next agent, etc.  If no agents are available, I'm clear on the FailURL.

But what about the success URL?  In other words, if the caller picks up, I want to save which caller picked up to our database.

If the FindMe twimlet is not the best way to proceed, the IVR + Screening tutorial is close to what I want to do, it just demands a bit more code.  Would that be the preferred way to proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you're looking to perform something similar to the [FindMe Twimlet](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/findme) but need to integrate it with your system with details like who answered, then you probably do want to build it yourself.

The way the FindMe works is by using the [`action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action) of the [`<Dial>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) verb to recursively call the same URL with a new number to dial every time a number you try to call doesn't answer.

In order to record when the phone is answered you actually need to use the [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number) verb's [`statusCallbackUrl` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback-event). You can get webhooks back to your application for the following events:

- initiated - when Twilio starts to dial the number
- ringing - when the number being dialed starts to ring
- answered - when the call is answered
- completed - when the call is over, for whatever reason

You would need the answered event in this case as you could then record the number that answered.

Let me know if that helps at all.